# Отправить сообщение через vk_api с форматированием текста

Tags: vkontakte-api

Как мне отправить сообщение через vk_api с форматированием текста. Чтобы можно было использовать жирный шрифт, курсив, гиперссылки и отступы? Ниже мой пример использования эхо-бота.

```
if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
  self.api.messages.send(message=event.object.text,
                         random_id=get_random_id(),
                         peer_id=event.object['peer_id'])
```

Comment: а почему вы решили, что так можно?

Comment: Хм. Я не уверен, что так можно. Интересуюсь. Может кто-нибудь знает как?